# how to set silverlight out of browser application in windows startup

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

Hi
I have one silverlight application which I have set for Out of browser application so that user can installed on their machine.

Now my question is "Is there any way or configuration or programmatically  possible that when my silverlight application get installed it will put it self in the windows startup so that when user logged in it will automatically starts like messenger applications (yahoo, msn etc)?"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a batch file that would do 2 things :

1. Install your app in OOB using SLLauncher.exe (silverlight executable fo OOB applications), It now have a /install option in its parameters you could use that method to install it.
2. Copy the shortcut to the"Startup" folder of the current user :

   %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup